# Hiding a column that appears within an entered range

Tags: excel, vba

In my data sheet, I want to allow users to hide whichever columns they want, but column F cannot be hidden.  When the user wants to hide a column, they push a button which brings up an input form, and they can enter the column(s) they want to hide.   I have it working if column F is specifically mentioned(i.e. user inputs  "F" or "A,C,F,G" etc), but I'm not sure how to go about if they enter it as a range and F isn't specified (i.e.  A-G, E-I, etc.).   Here's the code that I have:

```
If Len(TheColumn) <= 2 Then
    If Hide = True And TheColumn = "F" Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, you cannot hide column F", vbOKOnly, "Action cancelled!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Else
    If InStr(1, TheColumn, ",F,") > 0 Or InStr(1, TheColumn, ",F") > 0 Or Left(TheColumn, 1) = "F" Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, you cannot hide column F", vbOKOnly, "Action cancelled!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

I thought about using ASC to find out if ASC("F") is between the ASC of the first and last letters, but it only counts the first character, so ASC("AA") is the same as ASC("A"), which could cause issues if you want to hide "Z-AB"

Also just realized my code below won't work if they enter a range that doesn't encompass F (i.e  A-D) anyway.

```
sStart = 1
Do Until sStart > Len(TheColumn)
    sEnd = InStr(sStart, TheColumn, ",") - 1
    If sEnd = -1 Then sEnd = Len(TheColumn)
    col = Mid(TheColumn, sStart, sEnd - sStart + 1)
    If Show = True Then
        Range(col & "1").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        Range(col & "1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
    sStart = sEnd + 2
Loop
```

Comment: Create a `Range` object based on their input and see if it `Intersect`s column F.

Comment: Or  just make sure column F is not hidden at the end of the code, hiding all others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to make it usable for `Range` to hide columns in one line instead of using loops. At the end of code you just make sure that column `F` is always visible.

```
Sub F()
    Dim cols, re
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Global = True: re.Pattern = "([A-Z]{1,2})(?=,|$)"
    cols = "A,C,E,F": cols = re.Replace(cols, "$1:$1") '=> A:A,C:C,E:E,F:F
    Range(cols).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("F").Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Comment: When I try that, it only hides A,C,E,F, regardless of what the user specifies.  
 Replacing "cols = "A,C,E,F":" with cols = TheColumn, it gives me an error - Runtime 1004 Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed, and it highlights the "Range(cols)" line and shows cols has a value of A-G:G, or A:G:G, depending how it's entered.

TheColumn is a variable set to pull the data from a text box where the user enters the columns they want to hide.

Comment: @wrios This is the example. This means that `cols` must contain a string with list of columns. However, this code doesn't handle case when user inputs a range (`A-G`, for example).